# mvn jboss:deploy fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, maven-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

When deploying an EJB project to JBoss using JBoss Maven Plugin, I get a NoClassDefFoundError on my JBoss' console about a class that is in one of the dependencies of this EJB project.

This dependency is declared with a Compile scope. Is there another scope that I should use so that my dependencies are also deployed to JBoss? Or how should I solve this?

The error looks like this:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/Users/hordine/projects/SoftBudget/soft-budget-ejb/target/soft-budget-ejb.jar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/pedra/j2eepatterns/facade/IEntityService
```

Comment: What is your ejb package? jar, war or ear?

Comment: As a jar. I don't want to have to deploy the dependencies separately, by copying them to the server lib folder, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have packaged the EJB as a jar file. This means there is no any provided dependency as same as a stand-alone jar.

AFAIU, there may be 3 possible ways as the following: -

1. Package them as an `ear` and put those dependencies inside the `ear/lib`. Please see [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) for further information.
2. Package them as an `war` and put those dependencies inside the `WEB-INF/lib`. Please see [Maven WAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) for further information.
3. Package them as an `jar` and put those dependencies inside the `classpath` or `application server lib`. Please refer to your application server document.

**EDITED:**
If you are using the `JavaEE 6`, then it is possible to package the `EJB` as a `war` file. The [The Java EE 6 Tutorial: Packaging Enterprise Beans in WAR Modules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html) told us as

> Enterprise beans often provide the business logic of a web application. In these cases, **packaging the *enterprise bean* within the *web application’s WAR module*** simplifies deployment and application organization. Enterprise beans may be packaged within a WAR module as Java programming language class files or within a JAR file that is bundled within the WAR module.
>
> To include `enterprise bean` class files in a `WAR module`, **the class files should be in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory**.
>
> To include a `JAR file` that contains `enterprise bean`s in a `WAR module`, **add the `JAR` to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the WAR module**.
>
> *WAR modules that contain enterprise beans do not require an `ejb-jar.xml` deployment descriptor. **If the application uses `ejb-jar.xml`, it must be located in the `WAR` module’s `WEB-INF` directory**.*

I hope this may help.

Comment: I packaged them as a jar, yes. Thanks for the options, but I don't want to deploy it inside an EAR and I don't think you can package EJBs as WAR. (or can you). I want to deploy them as Jar. I was afraid I'd have to deploy the dependencies separately, yes. I gave you a vote up, but let's see if someone else has a better idea.

Comment: If you are using the JavaEE6, it is possible to package the `EJB` as a `war`. Please see my edited for further information.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, it's nice to know all that, but I'm using JBoss 5 and JavaEE 5.